# Trying to do DetourAttach but cannot convert my lua function's datatype to LPVOID

Tags: c++, detours

So this is how my function actually looks like

```
DetourAttach(&(LPVOID&)lua_tolstring, (PBYTE)tostring);
```

`lua_tolstring` is `const char*` and `LPVOID` gives me this error.

```
typedef void* LPVOID
invalid type conversion
```

How can i make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have the right semantics for DetourAttach.  The first argument is a pointer-to-pointer-to-function, which should be initialized to the original function being hooked.  The second argument is a pointer-to-function containing your hook function.

See [This blog](http://zenersblog.blogspot.com/2008/04/api-hooking-with-detours-part-1.html) for examples.

So you can't just pass the function.  You have to initialize a variable, e.g.:

```
// Declaration of LUA API function in header
const char*lua_tostring (lua_State *L, int index);
// Your hook function must have this signature to match
const char*my_tostring (lua_State *L, int index);
// Your variable
const char* (*Real_lua_tostring)(lua_State *L, int index) = lua_tostring;
// Make the call
DetourAttach(&(LPVOID&)Real_lua_tolstring, (PVOID)my_tostring);
```